# Application Error : Heroku, Ruby on Rails 4, warnings: rails_12factor, vendor/bundle, no Procfile

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

My Ruby on Rails 4 application works well on Mac.

But when I tried to upload my application to Heroku, with the warning messages, the Heroku application hasn't worked, saying `application error` in the corresponding web page.

Here I put a log file including very mysterious terms such as `rails_12factor` and `procfile`:

```
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Include 'rails_12factor' gem to enable all platform features
remote:        See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-integration-gems for more information.
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Removing `vendor/bundle`.
remote:        Checking in `vendor/bundle` is not supported. Please remove this directory
remote:        and add it to your .gitignore. To vendor your gems with Bundler, use
remote:        `bundle pack` instead.
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
remote:        To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
remote:        ruby '2.0.0'
remote:        # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information.
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
remote:        Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 30.0MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v6
remote:        https://ringlebeta.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
```

And this this my Gemfile! I would love to hear any suggestions and opinions:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc


#Google Auth
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2", "~> 0.2.1"


# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

 # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
"Gemfile" 54L, 1596C
```

Comment: when I command "ruby -v", it says: ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]

Comment: You stated 'including very mysterious terms such as "rails_12factor" and procfile' - however, after every single "mysterious term" there is a link to a very extensive documentation. Have you read ANY of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku integration has previously relied on using the Rails plugin system, which has been removed from Rails 4. To enable features such as static asset serving and logging on Heroku please add rails_12factor gem to your Gemfile.

At the end of Gemfile add:

> gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

Then run:

bundle install and then try deploying:

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your Gemfile, then try deploying:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# ...
# Your Gemfile contents here
# ...

group :production do
  gem 'pg'   # If you plan to use PostgreSQL in your Heroku app
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

The `rails_12factor` is a gem provided by Heroku. It enables serving assets in production and setting your logger to standard out, both of which are needed to run a Rails app on a 12-factor provider.

Comment: Thanks! Still, I got the error from the Heroku with the two warnings still: vendor/bundle + No procfile.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the Procfile in the root directory. Inside the Procfile add the following line: `web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb`